# In darcs, is there a way to recover rolled-back patches?

Tags: darcs

In my darcs repo, I needed to rollback to look at a prior change. I made a copy of what I thought was the root directory, rolled back, and deleted.

Now I realize that the root was actually one directory up. So the repo I rolled back was actually my only copy.

Is there a way to access old commits in darcs, as there is in git?

Comment: How did you actually do the rollback? The "darcs rollback" command itself actually makes a new set of changes. Did you use "darcs obliterate" or "darcs unpull"?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I just did 'darcs rollback', so maybe I didn't realize the changes I was looking forr were a few patches back the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to recover rolled-back patches.

I did find some artifacts that I will now recover the recent changes from.

Note to self: when copying a repository, always use `darcs clone`, never `cp -r`. And check to verify where the repository root is.

Could also be helpful if darcs had more recovery features.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `darcs rollback` command, then the changes are just undone in the working directory. You can just use `darcs revert` to undo the rollback (i.e. redo the changes).

Comment: I actually did 'darcs rollback' and then 'darcs revert', to revert the changes.